Triangular array of random variables
Let $u:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be a continuous function. For $n\geq1$, let $\{X_{n,k}\}_{k=1}^n$ be independent random variables such that $X_{n,k}\sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}\left(u(\frac{k}{n})\right)$. That is, $P(X_{n,k}=1)=u(\frac{k}{n})$ And $P(X_{n,k}=0)=1-u(\frac{k}{n})$. Let $S_n$ denote the row sum $X_{n,1}+...+X_{n,n}$. I want to show that $\frac{S_n}{n}$ converges almost surely to some constant.
I was given the hint to consider the convergence of $n^{-1}E[S_n]+n^{-1}(S_n-E[S_n])$ and use Chebyshev's inequality by computing a high enough moment of $S_n-E[S_n]$. In doing so, I have ended up with the result that $E[|S_n-E[S_n]|^2]=0$, which does not seem correct, but I can't see where I'm going wrong in my work.
Fix $n\geq1$. Notice that $E[X_{n,k}]=1\cdot P(X_{n,k}=1)+0\cdot P(X_{n,k}=0)=P(X_{n,k}=1)=u(k/n)$. Hence $$E[S_n]=u(1/n)+...+u(1)$$ Denote $\mu_n:=E[S_n]$. To compute the 2nd moment, we note $E[|S_n-\mu_n|^2]=E[S_n^2]-\mu_n^2.$ First we find $$S_n^2=\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}X_{n,i}X_{n,j}$$ Notice that for any such $i,j$, $X_{n,i}X_{n,j}=1\iff X_{n,i}=1$ and $X_{n,j}=1$. Hence $E[X_{n,i}X_{n,j}]=P(X_{n,i}=1,X_{n,j}=1)=u(i/n)u(j/n).$ Therefore $$E[S_n^2]=\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}u(i/n)u(j/n)$$ But, $$\mu_n^2=(u(1/n)+...+u(1))^2=\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n} u(i/n)u(j/n)=E[S_n^2]$$ So $$E[|S_n-\mu_n|^2]=0$$ I can't find where I've gone wrong, but I also can't imagine that this result is true because then $S_n=\mu_n$ almost surely for all $n$. If anyone could guide me as to what I am not seeing that would be very much appreciated, thanks!!

As you noticed, it suffices to prove that
$$
\tag{*}Y_n:=\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(X_{n,k}-\mathbb{E}\left[X_{n,k}\right]\right)\to 0\mbox{ almost surely}.
$$
By the Borel-Cantelli lemma, it suffices to prove that for each positive $\varepsilon$,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P\left(\left\lvert Y_n\right\rvert>\varepsilon\right)<\infty.
$$
You can use Azuma-Hoeffding's inequality and get a bound of order $e^{-n\varepsilon}$, which is more than enough.
Alternatively, and maybe more in the spirit of what is asked in the opening post, you can bound the fourth moment of $Y_n$ by expanding, giving terms of the form $$\left(X_{n,k_1}-\mathbb E\left[X_{n,k_1}\right]\right)
\left(X_{n,k_2}-\mathbb E\left[X_{n,k_2}\right]\right)
\left(X_{n,k_3}-\mathbb E\left[X_{n,k_3}\right]\right)
\left(X_{n,k_4}-\mathbb E\left[X_{n,k_4}\right]\right)$$
and looking at different cases: when $k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4$ are all distinct, all equal, two are equal and the others are distinct. An upper bound for $\mathbb P\left(\left\lvert Y_n\right\rvert>\varepsilon\right)$ obtained in this way would be of the form $n^{-2}$.

Indeed we have not seen that inequality yet, but looking at the fourth moment worked. Thank you!

Note that
$$
\frac1n \mathbb{E} S_n=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n u(k/n)}n\to \int_0^1 u(x) dx
$$
(since $u$ is continuous). Also
$$
Var(S_n/n)=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n u(k/n)(1-u(k/n))}{n^2}\le \frac 1n
$$
since $0\le u\le 1$,
so
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{S_n}n- \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{S_n}n\right)\right|\ge \epsilon\right)
\le \frac1{n\epsilon^2}\to 0
$$
by Chebyshev, and thus
$$
\frac{S_n}n\to \int_0^1 u(x) dx
$$
in probability.

I think there's a small typo in equation 3, it should be $\geq\epsilon$ right? Otherwise, thank you!

I just realized this isn't enough to guarantee convergence almost surely. I think we need to compute a higher moment to get a better bound and then use Borel-Cantelli

Of course, $\ge \epsilon$, thanks, corrected.
Regarding convergence a.s., it is impossible to state it here as, in principle, $S_n$ do not have to be even defined on the same probability space.
